# How to apply a Shader in Blender 2.79?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, blender-internal-render-engine

Here the Shader download link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G5YJ8gyZ-JlIWHNZd25mmMMLRANBxj88/view?usp=sharing

1. I opened Blender 2.79b
2. I went to import > Wavefront (.obj) and loaded my model. I selected the model
3. I switched from 3D View to Node Editor and checked the "Use nodes" checkbox
4. I went to Append > EngravingShader.blend > NodeTree > NodeGroup
5. I went to Add>Group>NodeGroup

Where do I connect the NodeGroup points so that the shader works when rendering my image?[image: my blender screen]

Comment: The node group is like a texture, you could connect that directly to the output node. Also, if you select the node and press tab, you will see what's inside

Comment: Sorry, but what should I connect and where? In my NodeGroup, the points "Threshold", "Shader" and "Vector" do not connect at any point of the Output node. Only "Lines" connects to "Color" or "Alpha" of the Output. When I connect "Lines" to "Color" and/or "Alpha", it doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately as it stands this question doesn't seem to be answerable without more details. Without knowing what that node group contains or what it is supposed to do it is a blind guess telling how to use it. Judging from the screenshot I'd even dare saying that is a Cycles shader node and you are attempting to use it in a Blender Internal material, which is most likely incompatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the shader, we can see a green socket, which doesn't exist in Blender Renderer, so this shadergroup can be used in either Cycles or Eevee or another engine.

Then, looking inside the nodegroup, you should see an "undefined" node in red. That means the node isn't recognized by the Blender version you are using, either because the node was created in newer versions of Blender or for a render engine that isn't installed in your version.
But in your case, opening this shadernode in the current Blender 2.93 reveals that node to be a "Shader to RGB" node, which was introduced in Blender 2.8 series for Eevee render engine only.

In other words, this nodegroup is not compatible with Blender 2.79. You need to update.